# How to return a date value using a Public Function

Tags: excel, date, vba

I want to use a function that returns the most recent date from a series of dates.

```
Public Function RecentDate() As Date

Dim MaxDate As Date
Sheets("Data").Activate
MaxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))

End Function
```

However, when I use this function within a sub I get: 00:00:00. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub ShowDate()

MsgBox (RecentDate())

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Function RecentDate`, but you never set the value of `RecentDate` to the value of `MaxDate`.

Anyway, you don't realy need an extra vairable `MaxDate`, and there's not need to `Activate` the "Data" worksheet.

Change your `Function` code to:

```
Public Function RecentDate() As Date

RecentDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Data").Columns("A"))

End Function
```